# BC30002: Type 'MySqlConnection' is not defined - once code is on Web Server

Tags: html, mysql, asp.net, vb.net, ftp

I am creating a web site in Visual Studio 2013 Web Express using ASP and VB. The code works 100% fine in localhost, but once I FTP transfer my files over to my school's server, it no longer works. The web server comes up with an error message (Title) and says it stopped at here:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Partial Class Home
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private conn As New MySqlConnection
```

I've read many people having problems with this before but they all only stated the same answers that I've tried (will list below)

- First off, just want to remind everyone that this does work on my local computer
- I do have a working reference on my system to MySql.Data.dll
- I have tried several different versions of this
- I have tried not installing the Connector/Net for MySQL and ONLY referencing a MySql.Data.dll from within my Bin Folder. This works, confirming that they should not have to install the Connector/Net on their server.
- It is in my Bin folder, which is located at the same level as my web pages
- When I have uploaded my web site to the FTP server with MySQL.Data.dll targeting .Net 4.0, it did display an error, saying this was too high of a target since my project is in .Net 3.5
- As a note, the .Net files I am getting for MySQL.Data.dll target .Net 2.0, since that's the next lowest from 4.0

Thanks to reading, any input is appreciated. I'll supply as much information as I can if there's any questions.

Comment: Whether or not you have installed Connector/Net on your own system, simply set the `Copy Local` property of the `MySql.Data.dll` reference to `True`.  When you build, that DLL will be copied to the output folder along with your own assembly(s).  Deploy the entire output and you are good to go.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Good tip, however I believe since my project was created as a Web Site (according to what I've read online) I'm lacking those properties. Specifically, when I go to the Solution Explorer, I find the Mysql.Data.dll file inside my Bin folder. When I go to edit the Properties of the dll, it only states the File Name and the Full Patch, both not editable. I'm not sure if there's another way to do this, but the option is definitely not there.

Comment: You don't do anything to the file in the bin folder.  That's the destination, not the source.  As I said, you modify the property of the reference, which you access on the References page of the project properties.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I can get to the References page under the Property Page for my project. Since it is located in my Bin folder, the Mysql.data.dll is not located on this page and I can not add it as a reference because it states it is already being references (just by being in my bin folder I believe). Alternatively, I did try removing it from my Bin folder and referencing it from a different source, which adds it to the list. However, at this point there's no option anywhere to edit the properties of the reference. There's only Add, Remove, and Update (grayed out).

Comment: You edit the properties in the Properties window, just like you do for anything else.  Select the reference, open the Properties window and set the `Copy Local` property.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put the image files under the Views folder.  The URL you specify in the view is relative to the application itself, so you images folder should be under the project folder.